# creating rabbitmq vhost with kombu

Tags: rabbitmq, kombu

I am looking for a way to create and configure vhosts in rabbitmq with kombu but found nothing in the documentations. Is there a way to do so?
In addition - is there a permission / role in rabbitmq (other than admin) that allows to create vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not familiar with kombu, but if it can call an external command, namely rabbitmqctl, than it could use it to create the vhost. Also there is way by using the [http API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html) (just look for *create a new vhost*).
2. You can create a new user (using the aforementioned methods or WebUI) and give it any permission you want - if tagged as *administrator* that user will be able to create new vhosts.